# Property 'onMessage' does not exist on Type 'Message Payload'

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement browser push notification in Angular using firebase
followed this link

> https://www.devstringx.com/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications

Property 'onMessage' does not exist on type 'MessagePayload'

> messaging.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/compat/messaging';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'

@Injectable()

export class MessagingService {currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {

  this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
(_messaging) => {
_messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
_messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
}
)
}requestPermission() {
this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(
(token) => {
console.log(token);
},
(err) => {
console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
}
);
}receiveMessage() {
this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
(payload) => {
console.log("new message received. ", payload);
this.currentMessage.next(payload);
})
}
}
```

getting error

> ```
> Property onMessage does not exist on type 'MessagePayload'
> Property 'onTokenRefresh' does not exist on type 'MessagePayload'
> ```

```
_messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
_messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
```

firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.2/firebase-app.js'); 
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.2/firebase-messaging.js');firebase.initializeApp({ 
apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
authDomain: "xxxxxxxx", 
projectId: "xxxxxxxx", 
storageBucket: "xxxxxxx",
messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxx",
appId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
measurementId: "xxxxxxxxx"
});const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Any solution to fix this issue, Thanks